# C# How to drag drop a firefox tab to a winform application

Tags: c#, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

In firefox, you can dragdrop tabs to either bookmarks or any text field, but is it possible to drag drop these tab outside of firefox?

Also, is there a better way than

```
string vHTMLNames = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Html, false);
```

to get a dragdrop of html adress? (It is annoying to have to scan the string to find the adress lost into the spam of text that get returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag a tab out of firefox it spawns a new window.  So I don't think you can intercept this.

Comment: IT never opened a new window. It just does nothing.

Comment: @Wildhorn: must depend on the version; here on 3.6.2 on windows, it definately spawns a window if I drag a tab out.

Comment: You are right, I got it to open new one. But depending where you drop it, it will or not open one. Most likely when I tried before replying first time, I always dropped it somewhere it would not make it open one (seems dropping it in a textbox doesnt open a new window).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible. Maybe you need to write your own FF plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@Wildhorn, when you say "tab", what you really want is the "icon" to the left of the address bar.

Just as you can make shortcuts to the desktop dragging the icon, you can't with  a tab. Likewise, you can drag the icon onto a windows form control, but not a tab.

Also, use `DataForms.Text` rather than `DataForms.Html` to just get the URL.

```
string vHTMLNames = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text, false);
```